# Projecting a ray from screen to model for picking

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, 3d, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying cast a ray from mouse click position on screen and transform it into the model space for triangle intersection testing. I'm sure the intersection code works fine and I understand the theory behind unprojecting the ray. However my code doesn't work. I've tried several implementations for the same basic idea, and the results I'm getting seem to be all over the place.

Is there something fundamental missing from the code below?

```
 // 1. Convert x, y from screen to normalized device coordinates [-1:1]
auto screenPos = pick->position();    
float x = (2.0f * screenPos.x()) / Viewer::window()->width() - 1.0f;
float y = 1.0f - (2.0f * screenPos.y()) / Viewer::window()->height();

// 2. Create a ray xy coordinates with a z pointing forward
QVector3D ray = QVector3D(x, y, -1.0f);

// 3. Convert from device space to view space using inverted projection matrix
QMatrix4x4 projectionMatrix = Viewer::window()->camera()->projectionMatrix();
ray = ray * projectionMatrix.inverted();

// 4. Convert from view space to world space using inverted view matrix
QMatrix4x4 viewMatrix = Viewer::window()->camera()->viewMatrix();
ray = ray * viewMatrix.inverted();
ray.normalize();

// 5. Convert from world space to object space using object transformation matrix
QMatrix4x4 modelMatrix = this->transform()->matrix();
ray = ray * modelMatrix.inverted();
ray.normalize();

// 6. Get camera position for ray origin and transform it to object coordinates
QVector3D camera_pos = Viewer::window()->camera()->position();
QVector3D origin = camera_pos * modelMatrix.inverted();

// 7. Find intersections
auto intersection = testRay(mesh.get(), origin, ray);
```

Comment: I think you should multiply from the left with the inverses, because: out_vertex = projection * view * model * in_vertex

Comment: By any chance your `mesh` is not in global coordinates? The code looks all right otherwise...

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am having similar issues creating a world ray from mouse coordinates.